# How to touch toggle hidden under png image sprite in Unity3d

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, touch, toggle

I have a scrollable set of toggles partially hidden under png image. The image serves as a "border" for the toggles. The problem is that if the image is in hierarchy on top of the toggle (what I want for composition reasons) the toggles stop to work. Is there a way to make image ignore touches and not prevent touches of toggles under it? I know that I  can cut image into borders and get rid of the transparent hole but maybe there is simpler way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically solve this problem by adding a `Canvas Group` component to the transparent element.

Canvas Group Documentation - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html

It has a property that allows you to set a UI Element to a "Non-Interactable" state, which will allow you to click / touch through it with your event system.

[image]